# Why the length of the the rod contracts as the time passes more and more?

Tags: special-relativity

My question may be too obvious but please consider me as an apprentice into the special theory of relativity.  Suppose i take a stick moving at relativistic speed v in the positive x axis . I want to measure its length. But one end earlier at time $t_1$ (of my watch aka an inertial observer's watch) and the other end at another end at time $t_2$(of my watch aka an inertial observer's watch). In this pursuit i'll not get the proper length of the stick but little more as I'm taking more time to measure its length it has moved away.  Now the difference of space is $x_2'-x_1'= \frac{(x_2-x_1)-v(t_2-t_1)}{\sqrt{1-v^2/c^2}}$ but as the $t_2$ is my clock time then how the length of the rod measured in greater time interval gets more shorter. It should be proportional to the time interval instead it contracts more as we take more time to measure. Where am i wrong?

Comment: There are two separate effects here: one effect from waiting longer before deciding to measure the other end, and the other from length contraction. In other words, you're not actually measuring the length of the stick, but the length of the stick plus the distance the stick travels in that time interval. Are you asking why waiting longer will make the stick appear longer? Because, at a given velocity, the length of the stick as observed by a stationary observer  will be contracted the same amount at any time.

Comment: @probably_someone if i wait and then measure the length then $t_2$ grows up to be larger and length becomes more shorter as i observe from the equation.  Now why this becomes shorter over time passes instead being longer ? Do you understand my problem now?